# Which geo-spatial clustering method should be used to implement clustering analysis with constraints on the USA map?

Tags: geolocation, cluster-analysis, k-means, dbscan

I need to form clusters along with a constraint which limits the sum of a variable in each cluster to some value within limits. I am trying to implement this as an R or Python code

I'm trying to form 5-6 regions on the map where the sum of dollar value for the sum of datapoints in each cluster should be equal.

I have data points of zipcodes along with their latitude, longitude and Dollar value.

I tried implementing this using DBSCAN Technique. However, I am not able to add the extra constraint of equal dollar value.

Answer (score 1):

Clustering algorithms won't just allow you to add such constraints as they will likely contradict the objective of the clustering itself.

Try treating this as an optimization problem, and use for example an integer linear programming solver to optimize this.